# Exponentially distributed random generator (log function) in python?

Tags: python, random, distribution, exponential

I really need help as I am stuck at the begining of the code.

I am asked to create a function to investigate the exponential distribution on histogram. The function is x = −log(1−y)/λ. λ is a constant and I referred to that as lamdr in the code and simply gave it 10. I gave N (the number of random numbers) 10 and ran the code yet the results and the generated random numbers gave me totally different results; below you can find the code, I don't know what went wrong, hope you guys can help me!! (I use python 2)

```
import random
import math

N = raw_input('How many random numbers you request?: ')
N = int(N)
lamdr = raw_input('Enter a value:')
lamdr = int(lamdr)

def exprand(lamdr):
    y = []
    for i in range(N):
        y.append(random.uniform(0,1))
    return y
y = exprand(lamdr)
print 'Randomly generated numbers:', (y)

x = []
for w in y:
    x.append((math.log((1 - w) / lamdr)) * -1)
print 'Results:', x
```

Comment: different from what? you mean you run it twice and you get different results each time?

Comment: I got two lists for random numbers and the results, which should depends on the given equation, but it doesn't match, so for example I got totally x values for the randomly generated y values

Comment: Are you expecting `lambdr` to be the seed value for your `random.uniform()` calls?  You would need to seed it with `random.seed(lambdr)` first if so.  Then you would get the same sequence of numbers for a given `lambdr` value.

Comment: above I meant totally different x values by the way. Besides I don't know how to seed my lamdr value it says it is not defined, I mean it is just a constant that you determine for the equation

Comment: Without specifying a seed value, you're going to get a different sequence from `random.uniform()` each time you run the script.  Therefore, I would expect that your `x` values would be different, since your `y` values are also different.  Also, in the code as written above, you aren't actually doing anything with the `lambdr` value in the `exprand()` function.  You're just passing it along.  I'm not sure what you were intending to do with it in `exprand()`.

Comment: I am asked to create a exprand function with the argument of 'lamdr', that is why I have written it that way. I run the code for once and it still doesn't properly work. The problem in my question is actually not complicated, it is just that I couldn't manage to get a result (x values as a list) based on the math equation that have randomly generated y values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4):

After viewing the code you provided, it looks like you have the pieces you need but you're not putting them together.

You were asked to write function `exprand(lambdr)` using the specified formula.  Python already provides a function called `random.expovariate(lambd)` for generating exponentials, but what the heck, we can still make our own.  Your formula requires a "random" value for `y` which has a uniform distribution between zero and one. [The documentation for the `random` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) tells us that `random.random()` will give us a uniform(0,1) distribution.  So all we have to do is replace `y` in the formula with that function call, and we're in business:

```
def exprand(lambdr):
    return -math.log(1.0 - random.random()) / lambdr
```

**An historical note**: Mathematically, if `y` has a uniform(0,1) distribution, then so does `1-y`. Implementations of the algorithm dating back to the 1950's would often leverage this fact to simplify the calculation to `-math.log(random.random()) / lambdr`. Mathematically this gives distributionally correct results since P{X = c} = 0 for any continuous random variable X and constant c, but computationally it will blow up in Python for the 1 in 2<sup>64</sup> occurrence where you get a zero from `random.random()`.  One historical basis for doing this was that when computers were many orders of magnitude slower than now, ditching the one additional arithmetic operation was considered worth the minuscule risk. Another was that Prime Modulus Multiplicative PRNGs, which were popular at the time, never yield a zero.  These days it's primarily of historical interest, and an interesting example of where math and computing sometimes diverge.

Back to the problem at hand.  Now you just have to call that function `N` times and store the results somewhere.  Likely candidates to do so are loops or list comprehensions.  Here's an example of the latter:

```
abuncha_exponentials = [exprand(0.2) for _ in range(5)]
```

That will create a list of 5 exponentials with λ=0.2.  Replace 0.2 and 5 with suitable values provided by the user, and you're in business. Print the list, make a histogram, use it as input to something else...

Replacing `exporand` with `expovariate` in the list comprehension should produce equivalent results using Python's built-in exponential generator.  That's the beauty of functions as an abstraction, once somebody writes them you can just use them to your heart's content.

Note that because of the use of randomness, this will give different results every time you run it unless you "seed" the random generator to the same value each time.

Answer (score 2):

WHat @pjs wrote is true to a point. While statement `mathematically, if y has a uniform(0,1) distribution, so does 1-y` appears to be correct, proposal to replace code with `-math.log(random.random()) / lambdr` is just wrong. Why? Because Python `random` module provide U(0,1) in the range [0,1) (as mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)), thus making such replacement non-equivalent.

In more layman term, if your `U(0,1)` is actually generating numbers in the [0,1) range, then code

```
import random
def exprand(lambda):
    return -math.log(1.0 - random.random()) / lambda
```

is correct, but code

```
import random
def exprand(lambda):
    return -math.log(random.random()) / lambda
```

is wrong, it will sometimes generate NaN/exception, as `log(0)` will be called

Comment: A comment or edit seems like a more appropriate response than a down-vote.